# Understanding CatBoost Classifier trees with categorical features

Tags: python, tree, categorical-data, catboost

I am using CatBoost Classifier in python in order to train boosted trees. Unfortunately, the deployment has to be done in a different programming language, thus I cannot use the predict method that is already available, but I have to implement it myself. I tried exporting the model to a json file and reconstring the trees (thus doing scoring) by myself. It works perfectly fine when there are no categorical features. However, if I use categorical features (one-hot-encoded or not), I do not understand the values in the json file. For example, I have such a split in my tree:

> {
>      "split_index":16,
>      "cat_feature_index":0,
>      "value":1127826985,
>      "split_type":"OneHotFeature"
>   }.

The feature that gets one-hot encoded (the one with the cat_feature_index = 0) takes 4 different values in my data (100,200,700 and 800). I would like to know what exactly does this split do.

Moreover, if I don't use one-hot-encoding, one of the splits looks like:

> {
>      "split_index":15,
>      "split_type":"OnlineCtr",
>      "border":4.99999999046,
>      "ctr_target_border_idx":0
>   },

where the feature and the data are the same as above. What exactly does this split do?

Could you, please, tell me where can I find explanation of the trees and/or the source code where the splits in the trees with categorical features are defined?